# UISearchDisplayController not showing

Tags: iphone

I've been doing everything programmatically in the past, but now I'm trying to learn to use Interface Builder. An experience in and of itself.

My problem is with `UISearchDisplayController`. Just dropping it on top of my `UITableViewController` (see figure 1) *should* set up all relevant connections (and I think add it to the `tableView` header), and as such it should (?) show up when I run the app. But no! Nothing shows up (see figure 2). Has anyone had any similar experiences, or know what the problem might be?

[Figure 1](http://joacim.pilointeractive.se/1.png)

[Figure 2](http://joacim.pilointeractive.se/2.png)

It's a navigation based app - if that makes any difference - with the navigation part of the app set up programmatically like so:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    bookmarksController = [[BookmarksViewController alloc] init];
    bookmarksController.managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:bookmarksController];
    [bookmarksController release];

    [self.window addSubview:navController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I had to explicitly point out which NIB to load:

```
bookmarksController = [[BookmarksViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BookmarksViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you! I was about to sink in despair over this. I really can't see why it wouldn't load the xib file I created along with my controller .h & .m files.

Answer (score 2):

in the ViewDidLoad method:

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.hidden = NO;
```

if that dosen't help then check all the connections in IB.
This a screenshot of the connections of the Files Owner in my tableview xib.

[image: IB connections]

If even this dosen't help, please comment and I will try to figure out something else.

Comment: Didn't help I'm afraid. My connections are made up similarly ([link](http://joacim.pilointeractive.se/3.png)), completely unaltered.

Comment: does the searchbar appear if during build and run you drag the cells down?

Comment: Solved it. I'll update the question with an answer. Thanks for your help!